# How to fix below issue ? Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

While I am executing below stored procedure it will result a error in my webpage. Error is

> Procedure or function 'AuditsReportForLPA' expects parameter '@Division', which was not supplied

Here is asp.net markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlAudits" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TESTQTYConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="AuditsReportForLPA" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
     <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlAuditType" Name="AuditType" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision" Name="Divison" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDateFrom" Name="dateFrom" 
                PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDateTo" Name="dateTo" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlAuditedBy" Name="name" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AuditsReportForLPA]
    @AuditType NVARCHAR(75),
    @Division NVARCHAR(10),
    @dateFrom DATETIME,
    @dateTo DATETIME,
    @name VARCHAR(14)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Division = '003'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.view_LPA_Audits_with_Names
        WHERE division  = '001' OR division = '002' OR division = '003'
          AND auditdate BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo
          AND ISNULL(AuditType, '') LIKE @AuditType
        ORDER BY auditdate
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.view_LPA_Audits_with_Names
        WHERE division LIKE @Division
          AND auditdate BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo
          AND ISNULL(AuditType, '') LIKE @AuditType
        ORDER BY auditdate
    END
END
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to use a SqlDataSource? They're really not recommended for use. Instead, you can call that stored procedure from C# to get your data, and then return that data to your UI layer. This keeps proper Separation of Concerns, avoiding leaking database implementation details into your UI logic.

Comment: ya  here I want to use SqlDataSource

Comment: @VincyJoseph When you try to execute the stored procedure what is the selected value of the `ddlDivision` dropdown?

Comment: values are 000, 001, 002, 003, 005, 0025

Comment: `ControlID="ddlDivision" Name="Divison"` you mistyped `division`